# Grid Panel Scrollbars in Extjs 4 not working

Tags: extjs4

```
var gusersPanel = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    flex:1,
    columns: [{
        header: 'User Login',
        dataIndex: 'user_login',
        width:150
    },{
        header: 'User Name',
        dataIndex: 'user_nicename',
        width:150
    },{
        header:'Privledge',
        dataIndex:'admin',
        width:150
    }],
    autoScroll: true,
    layout:'fit',
    selModel: gusersSel,
    store: gusersStore
```

})

Hi I am using above code for the grid Panel in Extjs4.0.2a When I populate data dynamically in the store the scrollbars are not working .
I have also tried using doLayout() for grid Panel but dosent work too .
The grid Panel is in a Window .

Anything that can solve this problem ?

Actually it works for some time but dosen't work all the time .

Comment: I did gusersPanel.determineScrollbars() when i am adding and removing data from store and it is working fine .

Answer (score 12):

I've had the same problem. They use custom scrollbar and it's pretty buggy (especialy in chrome). If you are not going to use infinite scroll the possible solution could be to remove custom scrollbar and use native one. To do that just add the following to the grid's config:

```
var gusersPanel = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
  scroll          : false,
  viewConfig      : {
    style           : { overflow: 'auto', overflowX: 'hidden' }
  },
  // ...
});
```

Comment: I did gusersPanel.determineScrollbars() when i am adding and removing data from store and it is working fine . Thanks for your answer

Comment: This workaround is quite useless as it breaks other grid features.

Comment: @ArturBodera, do you have better one?

Comment: Sorry, no. I've tried every single solution and tried every available API method to fix scrollbars once they lock up, nothing helps which means you'd have to tear down the whole component and re-create it. My fingers are crossed for 4.1, because it dumps virtual scrolling. Unfortunatelly 4.1 is too buggy as of today (04.2012).

Answer (score 9):

I did gusersPanel.determineScrollbars() when i am adding and removing data from store and it is working fine .

Answer (score 3):

The problem with this is the scroll listener is attached to the div element on the afterrender event, but then if the scrollbar is not needed after a layout operation the div element is removed from the dom. Then, when it's needed again it's added back, but only if enough time has passed the garbage collection makes extjs recreate the div node and this time it's added to the dom without attaching the scroll listener again. The following code solves the problem:

```
Ext.override(Ext.grid.Scroller, {
    onAdded: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        var me = this;
        if (me.scrollEl) {
            me.mun(me.scrollEl, 'scroll', me.onElScroll, me);
            me.mon(me.scrollEl, 'scroll', me.onElScroll, me);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: In my case when this 'onAdded' function is called 'me.scrollEl' is undefined so, it not works for me, do you know why?

Comment: Ext.grid.Scroller exists in 4.0 but it does not exist in 4.1 :|

Comment: Do you have the same problem with extjs 4.1+?

Answer (score 0):

You written code to layout: 'fit'. It did not work autoScroll.

Change the code to some height and remove layout: 'fit' code.

Like this.

```
var gusersPanel = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    flex:1,
    columns: [{
   ...........
    }],
autoScroll: true,
//layout:'fit',
height: 130,
selModel: gusersSel,
store: gusersStore
```

It is help you. Cheers.